# Hadoop compile using Maven needs to run surefire tests?

Tags: maven, hadoop

I am trying to compile `Hadoop 2.6.0` on `ubuntu 14` using `maven 3.1.1` using `Java 7` because I want to implement a new scheduler. I have found answers from Thomas Jungblut on stackoverflow that suggested to skip the surefire tests (mvn package -DskipTests) and that works. My question is if there's a downside to skipping the tests. This is the Error WITH the tests:

> "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project hadoop-common: There are test failures."

Secondly, I wonder why I should get a jar file as output because when I installed Hadoop I just extracted the tar file to my OS folder structure and setup the configuration from there. Not sure why I need to compile a jar file.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Toon

Answer (score 0):

If those tests have worked in other environment, usually it means that the tests are not written correctly:
 - are expecting a dependency to be installed in your system that does not exist.
 - are simply bad written, and depend on each other, and they are running in a different order in your system.

Maven build can generate also .tar.gz , if your compilation of Hadoop is only giving you a jar... you need to make sure you are building the right code. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, on this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9326 they discuss how the tests have problems running them as root or as user so I'm trying to look into this. I am not familiar to the tests in question.

Comment: I've managed to get passed the surefire issue, I hadn't installed Zlib devel and CMake which the BUILDING.txt file asked for. The directory where everything is compiled is under hadoop-dist/target and there I could find the tar.gz file.

Comment: Lucky you, it was just a dependency issue.

From my personal experience, the best is to upload the dependencies as artifacts so those are downloaded via Maven itself, but sometimes the dependecies are not portable and packaging them is not trivial.

Good job! :)